# How to zoom out graph programmatically via using GraphView?

Tags: android, android-graphview

I`m using graph library - *GraphView*. User can zoom in/zoom out graph. I want to zoom out graph on click button in the default state. Is there are any available methods that can zoom out graph programmatically? Or I should Override some standard gesture method.

If I should then what methods I have to override??

Show me way please!

Answer (score 1):

just change the viewport:

`mGraph.getViewport().setMinX(...);
mGraph.getViewport().setMaxX(...);
mGraph.getViewport().setMinY(...);
mGraph.getViewport().setMaxY(...);`